# NixOS, Haskell LSP in Neovim, XMonad imports are not found

Tags: haskell, neovim, nixos, xmonad

Here is a screenshot of the problem:
[image]

OS: NixOS, unstable channel.

Neovim: 0.7.2.

Haskell LSP: `haskell-language-server`.

Running `xmonad --recompile` in the terminal works.

Please help :-)

###### EDIT 1:

As asked by @ArtemPelenitsyn in the comments below, here is my `init.lua`: https://pastebin.com/70jMHm02.
The parts that I think relevant:

```lua
require'lspconfig'.hls.setup{}
```

I think it's something more related to NixOS and not to Neovim.

###### EDIT 2:

As asked by @Ben in the comments below, here is the needed info:

```
λ ghci
GHCi, version 9.0.2: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> import XMonad

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘XMonad’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
ghci>
```

Here is everything related to Haskell and XMonad in my configuration.nix:

```hs
# snip
services.xserver.windowManager.xmonad.enable = true;
services.xserver.displayManager.defaultSession = "none+xmonad";
services.xserver.windowManager.xmonad.enableConfiguredRecompile = true;
services.xserver.windowManager.xmonad.enableContribAndExtras = true;
# snip
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  ghc
  haskell-language-server
  haskellPackages.xmobar
  haskellPackages.xmonad
  haskellPackages.xmonad-contrib
];
# snip
```

Comment: I think you'd need to provide details about your neovim config.

Comment: How have you installed the xmonad Haskell packages (as opposed to the xmonad executable you're running in `xmonad --recompile`)? Can you, say, open `ghci` and `import XMonad` there? If all you've done is install `xmonad` as a package from `nixpkgs`, then this sounds about what I'd expect; `xmonad` the command will know about a `ghc` configured to see the `xmonad` package, but `haskell-language-server` will not.

Comment: My approach to xmonad on nixos is to make a cabal project for my xmonad build. I then manage that the same way I would any other Haskell development project on nix (which means HLS works the same way it does in any of my other Haskell projects), and install it into my environment the same way I would any other project I was building from source. I don't have xmonad compile itself from a configuration file in my homedir.

Comment: @Ben, the `cabal` thingy you are suggesting feels like a workaround (its just my personal feeling, I might be crazy :-)). I would prefer not to use it.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker For me personally it wasn't so a workaround to this problem as making xmonad fit better into the nix model, for the same reasons as I am gradually moving a lot of my programs (including things like vim) to being installed fully configured into the nix store, and not have them read dotfiles in my homedir. It means that those things are included in nix's generations mechanism, for example, so I can instantly roll back a change that doesn't turn out.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker Regardless, I believe you will need to have some GHC environment configured with the dependencies of your xmonad config, and configure HLS to use that GHC when you're editing your config. You would have the same problem on any other distro if you had installed an appropriate GHC into a private directory (not on your normal PATH), and then installed xmonad with a wrapper script pointing it to the private GHC, and then tried to use HLS to edit the config without telling it about the private GHC. (This is basically how nix works, so it is actually what you have done)

Comment: @RefaelSheinker The simplest approach might be to write a shell.nix with a `ghcWithPackages (ps: [ ps.xmonad ... ])` call in it, and then always enter that shell before you edit the file.  That way HLS would see the `ghcWithPackages` you created as the `ghc` on `PATH`, and might just work with no further configuration. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: Ah, I just saw your edit with the ghci/configuration.nix stuff! Yes, this is making sense now. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your configuration.nix, you have the following:

```hs
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  ghc
  haskell-language-server
  haskellPackages.xmobar
  haskellPackages.xmonad
  haskellPackages.xmonad-contrib
];
```

Here you actually *haven't* installed a GHC that can access the `xmobar`, `xmonad`, and `xmonad-contrib` packages. Installed you've installed a GHC that doesn't know about any packages, and separately installed those Haskell packages. Any executables in those packages will be added to the `PATH` environment variable (which is how you can actually run `xmonad`), but `PATH` isn't know GHC finds installed packages. You need another step to connect the installation of GHC with the packages, so that you (and `haskell-language-server`) can import them.

The reason is that the way GHC is expecting to work is that installing packages is a mutating operation on the file system. On a "normal" system you install GHC and it knows about the packages that were bundled with it, then you install another package like `xmonad` into a folder that GHc will look in for packages<sup>1</sup> and now the effect of running that same `ghc` program has changed.

Nix doesn't like that. Packages are supposed to be **immutable** in Nix. You can't change a GHC-without-xmonad into a GHC-with-xmonad after the fact.

So just installing `pkgs.ghc` isn't actually what you want. That package is already completely determined by the nix code that evaluates to, and the package it determines is a baseline `ghc` with no additional packages. Instead you need to create an entirely new package that consists of GHC installed with `xmonad`.

Fortunately, this is an extremely common need so there is already a wrapper function to *generate* this package for you. `haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages`<sup>2</sup>. This function takes a single argument, which must be a function you provide. That function will itself be called on a single argument which is the collection of Haskell packages available, and should return a list of which ones you want included in the GHC installation package you're building.

So that means what you actually want is something like this:

```hs
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
  haskell-language-server

  # If you want you can use `with hpkgs; [` to avoid explicitly
  # selecting into the hpkgs set on every line
  (haskellPackages.ghcWithPackages (hpkgs: [  
    hpkgs.xmobar
    hpkgs.xmonad
    hpkgs.xmonad-contrib
  ]))
];
```

Under the hood what `ghcWithPackages` actually does is install `ghc` and those packages, just as you did, but then it also creates a very small "wrapper package" around `ghc` that sets environment variables telling it where to find the specific set of packages you installed. The thing that gets added to `PATH` to provide commands like `ghc`, `ghci`, etc is not the underlying GHC, but the wrapped one.<sup>3</sup>

You don't really need to know any of this "under the hood" stuff, just that every time you need GHC to have a specific set of packages you need to create a new nix package with `ghcWithPackages`. Knowing that it's based on wrapper scripts can help you not stress about space being wasted though; if you have 100 Haskell projects they can all share any GHC versions and Haskell package versions that are common; it's only the tiny wrappers that you have 100 copies of.

This is also the basic model used by most programming languages that have direct support in nixpkgs (and even some other things that aren't strictly programming languages but can be extended by installing plugins after the fact). It doesn't work precisely the same way for every language, as it depends on what code had to be written around the packaging tools each language has. But the basic conceptual model is frequently something like this.

This is all documented in the [nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs); as opposed to the manual for Nix itself, or for NixOS. It has a section on [Languages and Frameworks](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/#chap-language-support) where you can find the documentation for how a number of programming language ecosystems are supported in nixpkgs. Although the Haskell section under that has been turned into a small paragraph telling you to go to a separate site for the [nixpkgs Haskell docs](https://haskell4nix.readthedocs.io/).

---

One final note: I'm not 100% sure whether `haskell-language-server` will just automatically pick up the `ghc` in your `PATH` and run with those packages, or if you need any further configuration. Since I am a Haskell developer I have a number of projects that each need different sets of available packages (or even GHC version in some cases), so I don't have *any* GHC (or HLS) installed at the `environment.system-packages` level; each of my projects has its own shell environment, ultimately generated from the projects `.cabal` file. This means I've never actually used `haskell-language-server` on "loose" Haskell files living outside of a project, and I'm not sure whether you need to do anything more to get it to work. But this is definitely what you need to get `ghci> import XMonad` to work (without dramatically changing how you do things).

---

<sup>1</sup> And I believe also update some registry files, but I'm not 100% across all of the details. They're not important for this level of explanation.

---

<sup>2</sup> And if you don't like the version of GHC (and everything else) contained in `haskellPackages`, all the other Haskell package sets also contain this `ghcWithPackages` function, such as `haskell.packages.ghc924`, `haskell.packages.ghc8102`, etc (the top level `haskellPackages` is one of these sets; whichever is determined to be a good default in the revision of nixpkgs you happen to be using).

---

<sup>3</sup> The environment variables I can see in the wrapper script all have `NIX_` in the name, so I suspect the base GHC packages in nixpkgs are patched to support this behaviour.

Comment: Wow! What a thoughtful answer. I now completely understand everything. And everything works. Thank you very much!

Comment: One more question please: where did you find this `ghcWithPackages` thingy, I cant seems to find any documentation for it.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker I've updated the end of my answer with links to the docs, where I learned about this. I haven't actually read that chapter in a very long time though (the separate readthedocs.io site is new to me).

Comment: Some more info can be found here: https://haskell4nix.readthedocs.io/nixpkgs-users-guide.html.